# How to install Chromadb on AWS EC2?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I need an help with AWS and Django.
I created AWS EC2 instance and installed django using `pip install django`.
But when I try to install chromadb, it freezes on the stage of installing hnswlib.
What is the reason?

This is my second time to deploy on AWS EC2. But at the first time, my client created instance and I only used it. And there was no issue.

But this time, I created instance and tried. I felt the speed is very slower than before. Are there any options of the speed of instance?

Comment: please list the error you are getting while installation

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as my `pip version` on EC2 instance was outdated. This is what worked for me:

```py
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install chromadb
```

It will take some time to build `hnswlib` wait for it to complete.

Comment: I solved this.
The reason why it took long time is that I used the small instance such as micro.
I used t3.large instance and it is fast to install the chromadb.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your storage using following command:

```bash
df -h
```

If root is using more that 70% to 80%, increase your storage. You can increase it by stopping instance and go to storage then click on volume id and increase the storage. Again verify storage using `df -h`.